# Table relations

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

I am pretty new to MYSQL database creation. I am familiar with much of the theory as that's all we have done in class.

What I have is a user database with an auto increment id for each user as the primary key.

I would like to make a new table that contains that id and an access level.

I am having troubles with getting this table to fill up when users are registered.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE access (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    access_id INT (100) DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY (access_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users (id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on your troubles?

Comment: when a user has been created in the primary table (not shown) the id is not carried over to this table.

Comment: What did you write to trigger this? It is not because you define a foreign key that the database will write an entry in table by itself.

Comment: Thanks that helped answer my question mostly. Another question is will this trigger work? This trigger is attached to the primary table.
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'access_fill'
    AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO access (id)
        VALUES (NEW.id);
    END
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Am not a mysql expert. Try it to see if it works. Then ask a new question in case you have problems with the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long to be a comment, so I'll make it an answer. I believe your design of the ACCESS table is wrong. I would suggest something like:

```
CREATE TABLE access 
( user_id INT NOT NULL
, access_id INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
,    CONSTRAINT PK_ACCESS PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
,    CONSTRAINT FK_USER_ACCESS FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
                REFERENCES USERS (user_id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE
                    ON UPDATE CASCADE                
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Things I have changed:

- I used `user_id` in both table USERS and ACCESS
- user_id is the primary key of access. I assume that several users can have the same access, and that one user cannot have more than one access.
- `user_id` is not `AUTO_INCREMENT` in access (since it is dependent of `USERS`).

However, if my assumptions are correct and there's a 1-1 relationship between `USERS` and `ACCESS` you might consider adding `ACCESS` as an attribute of `USERS`. I.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
( user_id INT NOT NULL 
, access  INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
,  <other attributes>
,    CONSTRAINT PK_USER PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

This will solve your initial problem on how to populate the `ACCESS` table. Since your `USERS` table exists already, you can add the column as:

```
ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD COLUMN access INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from marco. It requires a trigger. The trigger in this case is.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `asphodel`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` TRIGGER `asphodel`.`users_AFTER_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `users` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO access (id)
    VALUES (NEW.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I would also like to note, I also used Lennart's suggestion of changing the PK to user_id.

Comment: You need to provide a value for `access_id` as well. otherwise, you won't be able to insert a second row.

Comment: The value for access ID is defaulted to 0 giving the user a simple authentication level. This makes it easy too build around privileges. or at least that's what the plan is.

Comment: then it shouldn't be a Primary Key.